# redundant VPN connections over Expressroute private peering

Tags: azure, site-to-site-vpn, azure-networking

I have configured redundant VPN connections over expressroute private peering with private IPs. BGP is configured making router 2 backup using BGP as-path. Wondering how the traffic is sent back to on-prem routers there is active-passive configuration but it seems there is packet loss from Azure to on-prem. Effective routes on a nic in a VNet shows VPN-GW public IP as next hop. How is traffic forwarded to next-hop from there? Fear it is only ECMP?   Attaching topology. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QxAo.png) @kapilananth-MSFT

Comment: `packet loss from Azure to on-prem`. What throughput are we talking about?

Comment: There are just a few kbs sent on the backup tunnel from Azure side which are enough to cause problems. I have tested that this happens when LNG1 and LNG2 have same on-prem address space. I have tried to make LNG2 Address space more bigger so that LNG1 is preferred, but in that case failover does not work at all.